# Solution Built Failure due to Metadata File Missing (CS0006)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I run into weird problem here, I can see many posts with same error code, but they are in different issues.

I have several projects in one solution written with C#. Project A, B, C... The build order is A->B->C, however, I don't know why it keeps reporting that in path of project A is looking for C's dll file, which is missing and is not supposed to generate at this point. If I unload project C, there is no issue at all for the whole solution. If I build project C, it also reports that Metadata file C'dll file is missing on A's path.

I have tried the answers from other posts, like removing reference, and added them manually, setup configuration manager.... none of them solves my problem.

Any suggestions will help, thanks in advance. 
Here are some codes from from my project C.

1. The output file path of project C in csproj file.
2. Part of the inter-reference in Project C csproj file. C depends on A&B, and B depends on A. However, the error shows project C.dll is missing in project B's path. if I unload project B, then the error shows project C.dll is missing in project A's path.

   ```
    1.
    </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
     <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
     <DebugType>full</DebugType>
     <Optimize>false</Optimize>
     <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
     <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
     <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
   </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
     <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
     <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
     <Optimize>true</Optimize>
     <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
     <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
     <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
     <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
     <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
     <DebugType>full</DebugType>
     <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset
     </CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
     <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
     <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
     <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
     <Optimize>true</Optimize>
     <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
     <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset
     </CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
     <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
     </PropertyGroup>

      2. </ItemGroup>
         <ItemGroup>
         <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj">
         <Project>{0bb34464-5e16-41fb-a1ad-3103fa3ab8b0}</Project>
         <Name>ProjectB</Name>
         </ProjectReference>
         <ProjectReference Include="..\PrjectA\ProjectA.csproj">
         <Project>{f5ff02ce-9ca1-477e-9a81-a227a71f2444}</Project>
         <Name>ProjectA</Name>
         </ProjectReference>
        </ItemGroup>
   ```

Comment: Are you using project references or path references from once project to the other.  What do the inter-project references look like?  If you could give us a snippet of the csproj file, that would also be helpful.  There is not really enough information here to properly help you.

Comment: If your A project are referring to C project, one way is to add the project as an reference, Another way is to find the specific path dll and use reflection use the dll.

Comment: I am using the project references.  In project C, except the inter-project references, it also references to many other libraries, so the csproj file is quite long. In csproj file, the output path for project C seems fine. I have also tried to change the target framework version to keep them consistent in csproj file. I have attached some snippets of them. Thanks for help.

Comment: Another thing what I found abnormal is the project C is supposed to create .exe application, not .dll file. However, the error shows /Project A/ ProjectC.Dll file is missing, which is not existing at all.

Comment: Update for my last post, project C is supposed to create .exe application, not .dll file. I found that the error shows "/ProjectA/ProjectC.dll" is missing, if projectA is creating dll file. It will shows "/projectB/projectC.exe" metadata file is missing, if ProjectB is creating exe file. Not sure why it shows other project's path when building projectC.

Comment: And the error path is always the last Projectreference in the projectC.csproj.